# Spock mock repository findAll always return null

Tags: spring-boot, spock

[Service]

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RecordService {
    private final RecordRepository recordRepository;


    @Transactional
    public void bulkUpdateRecord(BulkUpdateRecordRequest[] requestDto) {
        Map<Long, BulkUpdateRecordRequest> recordsMap = Arrays.stream(requestDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(BulkUpdateRecordRequest::getId, record -> record));
        List<Record> records = recordRepository.findAllById(recordsMap.keySet());
        System.out.println("records = " + records);
    }
}
```

[Repository]

```java
public interface RecordRepository extends JpaRepository<Record, Long>, RecordCustomRepository {
}
```

[Test codes]

```
class RecordServiceTest extends Specification {

    RecordRepository recordMockRepo = Mock()
    RecordService recordService = new RecordService(recordMockRepo)

    def "bulkUpdateRecord"() {
        given:
        def request = new BulkUpdateRecordRequest()
        request.setId(1)
        request.setCount(20)
        request.setWeight(100)
        request.setWeightType(WeightType.KG)
        def record = Record.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .weightType(request.getWeightType())
                .weight(request.getWeight())
                .count(request.getCount())
                .recordType(RecordType.PERSONAL)
                .exerciseName("deadlift")
                .exerciseType(ExerciseType.BACK)
                .build()

        when:
        recordService.bulkUpdateRecord(request)

        then:
        recordMockRepo.findAllById(_ as List) >> [record]
    }
}
```

You know that I mocked `findAllById()` method that return [record]

But it always return null.

However, this problem does not occur with methods that look up a single entity like findBy~().

Is there any issue on my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because this:

```
recordMockRepo.findAllById(_ as List) >> [record]
```

... does not match to a call in the `RecordService` class:

```java
recordRepository.findAllById(recordsMap.keySet());
```

Because `recordsMap.keySet()` returns `Set` and not `List`. Change it on:

```
recordMockRepo.findAllById(_ as Set) >> [record]
```

And when you have the mock instruction without invocation count checking then it is better to have it in the `given` section, because it is not testing anything and does not belong to `then` section. Or you can add the test of invocation count like this:

```
1 * recordMockRepo.findAllById(_ as Set) >> [record]
```

Comment: You mean is this a problem because the type of the calling argument is incorrect? (`recordRepository.findAllById(---HERE---);` in `RecordService`

Comment: Yes, changing of `findAllById(_ as List)` in your test to `findAllById(_ as Set)` should solve that.

Comment: Solved. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped to you ;-)